# Database.EnsureCreated() not creating tables

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro

TournamentDbContext.cs:

```
public class TournamentDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TournamentDbContext(DbContextOptions<TournamentDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Tournaments> Tournaments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TournamentType> TournamentType { get; set; }
}
```

Program.cs

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var TournamentDb = services.GetRequiredService<TournamentDbContext>();
                DbInitializer.Initialize(TournamentDb);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
            }
        }

        host.Run();
    }
```

Initialize method:

```
public static void Initialize(TournamentDbContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        if (!context.Tournaments.Any())
        {
            context.TournamentType.Add(new Models.Tournaments.TournamentType { Id = 1, Type = "LAN EVENT" });
            context.Tournaments.Add(new Models.Tournaments.Tournaments { Id = 1, Name = "Dummy lan tournament", TournamentTypeId = 1, DateFrom = DateTime.Now, DateTo = DateTime.MaxValue, SalesOpen = DateTime.Now, SalesClose = DateTime.MaxValue, Active = true, DateCreated = DateTime.Now });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Whenever I run this, exception always gets thrown.
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
With the following stacktrace:

```
Stacktrace: StackTrace = "   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.System.IObserver<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String,System.Object>>.OnNext(KeyValuePair`2 keyValuePair)\r\n   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener
```

If I run a debugger, it gets past the EnsureCreated() method, but it doesn't create the tables. The exception gets thrown at: `!context.Tournaments.Any()`

Any ideas how to fix this?

**UPDATE**: I tried this on my laptop, same problem. I also tried doing the initial migration (add-migration, update-database) and changing `context.Database.EnsureCreated()` to context.Database.Migrate(). And the error is the same, except the problem occurs are `context.SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I have no idea what happens in that tutorial, or why that solution works.

I found out that services aren't built in program.cs yet, that's why the code won't work. A workaround that I'm using is this

```
    public static void Seed(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var TournamentDb = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TournamentDbContext>();
        DbInitializer.Initialize(TournamentDb);
    }
```

Inside Startup.cs, and I call in inside `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` using `Startup.Seed(services)`.

I don't know if this is how it's meant to be used, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar issue to you and it turned out to be because the database was created incorrectly initially so each subsequent time it tried to create the tables it would fail. My fix was to call .EnsureDeleted() ONCE before which deleted it and started from scratch and it worked after. Then just remove the EnsureDeleted if you dont want it to re-create it each time.

```
            db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Comment: Yeah, but isn't that obvious? If the database is created, in whatever shape, `EnsureCreated` won't re-create it.

Comment: The answer still helps in this context. I also initially created an invalid database and then did run the above sample exactly once in order to recreate everything

Answer (score 0):

Startup.ConfigureServices() seems to get called when the WebHost is built in your above line `var host = BuildWebHost(args);`.

Is it possible your model was causing an exception on `EnsureCreated`, which then went unnoticed due to the try...catch?  That's the issue I was having.  Same symptoms.  Try debugging through `context.Database.EnsureCreated();` and see if the catch block is hit.

As far as I can tell, your solution would do the same thing as the original code, just through a series of unnecessary function calls.